# Is there sum of all response times in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is there sum of all response times in JMeter HTML report?

I know JMeter produces excellent data like median etc, but there is need to have sum of all response times.

Is it possible to see it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JMeter's [.jtl result files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are normal CSV files so you can import it into [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) or equivalent and invoke [SUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) function on the `elapsed` column

   [image]
2. If you have only one iteration and several requests - you can put all the requests under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) and it will report the cumulative execution time of all its children
3. It's possible to use [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) so JMeter would send results to a database, once done you should be able to create a query in the DB or in [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to display the cumulative response time

Answer (score 0):

I used option 2 from Dmitri's answer recently and it worked perfectly for me in JMeter 5.4.1.

In the Transaction Controller remember to click the "generate parent sample" tick box.
[image]

Then in the results tree and HTML dashboard, you will see individual response times for each call and a parent time for the controller.
[image]